# Regex for finding if a phrase is present in any location in a string

Tags: python, regex

Let's say I have a list of phrases like `['apple pie', 'scented candle']`. And there are strings like the following.

```
    'Apple pie 8 pieces'
    'Heavenly scented cinnamon candle 6 pack'
```

I want to build a regex that will check if a string contains a particular phrase from the list. So ideally, a regex that can match the pattern `blah word1 blah blah word 2 blah` will work. Where `blah` can be an empty string. And `word1 word2` is a phrase in the list.
Hence, I should get apple pie for the 1st and scented candle for the 2nd string

Comment: So you're saying `scented candle` should match `scented cinnamon candle`. Yeah/No, it doesn't work like that...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe, here a regular expression might be unnecessary,

```
word_action_library={
    'apple pie': 'Apple pie 8 pieces',
    'scented candle': 'Heavenly scented cinnamon candle 6 pack'
   }

print list(value for key,value in word_action_library.iteritems() if 'apple pie' in key.lower())
print list(value for key,value in word_action_library.iteritems() if 'scented candle' in key.lower())
```

#### Output

```
['Apple pie 8 pieces']
['Heavenly scented cinnamon candle 6 pack']
```

Comment: But isn't it for this particular case only? I want to match it with any string that contains `apple` and `pie` in the same order as `apple pie`